# How are POST/PUT/DELETE data passed to APIs?

Tags: php, rest, api, http, http-request

I know that the data is passed through HTTP, but I'm not sure if I should be passing data through HTTP headers, or HTTP bodies. Which one is the convention for APIs?

Also, theoretically using PHP, which would be easier to process? Based on what I know, using headers seems to be the easiest method.

#### POST body

```
POST /api/v1/test_params.json HTTP/1.1
Host: rollrbla.de
Content-Length: 59
X-Target-URI: http://rollrbla.de
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Connection: Keep-Alive

Test-Parameter-1=Test-value-1&Test-Parameter-2=Test-Value-2
```

#### POST header

```
POST /api/v1/test_params.json HTTP/1.1
Test-Parameter-2: Test-Value-2
Host: rollrbla.de
Test-Parameter-1: Test-Value-1
Content-Length: 0
X-Target-URI: http://rollrbla.de
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Overall, what would be the best way to process this data, and what is the convention?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The body.**

Headers are supposed to describe the request, not encapsulate its payload.

Headers are *meta-data*.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at what a request looks like using body parameters and header parameters, and also some PHP examples (thanks to @RobertHarvey) and I've concluded that body parameters are the best way to go, as they do not require any special functions to read in PHP. I was just unsure of what they were, but now I understand completely.

#### POST Body

```
POST /api/v1/test_params.json HTTP/1.1
Host: rollrbla.de
Content-Length: 59
X-Target-URI: http://rollrbla.de
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Connection: Keep-Alive

Test-Parameter-1=Test-value-1&Test-Parameter-2=Test-Value-2
```

... is the best way to go. Thanks to everybody who helped me reach this conclusion.